# Why doesn't my boost::spirit rule compile for parsing a list of lists?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm trying to write a parser for Open Inventor .iv files using boost::spirit.

I have the following struct for VertexProperty nodes:

```
struct VertexProperty
{
   std::vector<std::vector<float> > vertices;
   std::vector<std::vector<float> > normals;
   std::vector<std::vector<float> > texCoords;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
   VertexProperty,
   (std::vector<std::vector<float> >, vertices)
   (std::vector<std::vector<float> >, normals)
   (std::vector<std::vector<float> >, texCoords)
   )
```

And the following rule for parsing it (which doesn't compile):

```
qi::rule<Iterator, VertexProperty(), Skipper> RULE_VertexProperty;
RULE_VertexProperty = lit("VertexProperty")
   >> char_('{')
   >> lit("vertex") >> char_('[')
   >> repeat(3)[qi::float_] >> *(char_(',') >> repeat(3)[qi::float_])
   >> char_(']')
   >> lit("normal") >> char_('[')
   >> repeat(3)[qi::float_] >> *(char_(',') >> repeat(3)[qi::float_])
   >> char_(']')
   >> lit("texCoord") >> char_('[')
   >> repeat(2)[qi::float] >> *(char_(',') >> repeat(2)[qi::float_])
   >> char_(']') >> char_('}');
```

Based on this rule, the following should result in a valid VertexProperty parse:

```
VertexProperty {
   vertex [ 0.0 0.0 1.0,
            1.0 1.0 1.0,
            1.0 0.0 1.0]
   normal [1.0 0.0 0.0,
           0.0 1.0 0.0,
           0.0 0.0 1.0]
   texCoord [0.0 0.0,
             1.0 0.0,
             1.0 1.0]
}
```

My assumption is that the problem is coming from how I'm trying to parse the comma separated tuples into a vector of a vector.

What is the correct way to parse a list of 3-tuples and or 2-tuples of the form:

```
[float float float, float float float, float float float]
```

using boost::spirit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** I misread the question. Here's the rewrite:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9a8c8ba7a963682)</kbd>**

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45d0540503b52efc)</kbd>** (with debug output)

```
struct V2 { float a, b;    } ;
struct V3 { float a, b, c; } ;
struct VertexProperty { 
    std::vector<V3> vertices, normals;
    std::vector<V2> texCoords; 
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(V2, a,b)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(V3, a,b,c)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(VertexProperty, vertices,normals,texCoords)

template <typename Iterator>
struct Parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, VertexProperty()> {
    Parser() : Parser::base_type(start) {
        v2 = qi::double_ >> qi::double_;
        v3 = qi::double_ >> qi::double_ >> qi::double_;

        vertexproperty = qi::lit("VertexProperty")
            >> '{'
            >> "vertex"   >> '[' >> (v3 % ',') >> ']'
            >> "normal"   >> '[' >> (v3 % ',') >> ']'
            >> "texCoord" >> '[' >> (v2 % ',') >> ']'
            >> '}';

        start = qi::skip(qi::space) [vertexproperty];

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((v2)(v3)(vertexproperty))
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, VertexProperty()> start;
    qi::rule<Iterator, VertexProperty(), qi::space_type> vertexproperty;
    qi::rule<Iterator, V2(),             qi::space_type> v2;
    qi::rule<Iterator, V3(),             qi::space_type> v3;
};
```

Notes:

- use a typed element instead of 'just' a vector
- use a separate rule for the V3
- use literals (`qi::lit`) instead of `qi::char_` because you do not want to expose the matched interpunction
- use the list operator (`a % b` matches `a [b a]...` already)

### UPDATE: Full Live Demo

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

struct V2 { float a, b;    } ;
struct V3 { float a, b, c; } ;
struct VertexProperty { 
    std::vector<V3> vertices, normals;
    std::vector<V2> texCoords; 
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(V2, a,b)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(V3, a,b,c)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(VertexProperty, vertices,normals,texCoords)

template <typename Iterator>
struct Parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, VertexProperty()> {
    Parser() : Parser::base_type(start) {
        v2 = qi::double_ >> qi::double_;
        v3 = qi::double_ >> qi::double_ >> qi::double_;

        vertexproperty = qi::lit("VertexProperty")
            >> '{'
            >> "vertex"   >> '[' >> (v3 % ',') >> ']'
            >> "normal"   >> '[' >> (v3 % ',') >> ']'
            >> "texCoord" >> '[' >> (v2 % ',') >> ']'
            >> '}';

        start = qi::skip(qi::space) [vertexproperty];

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((v2)(v3)(vertexproperty))
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, VertexProperty()> start;
    qi::rule<Iterator, VertexProperty(), qi::space_type> vertexproperty;
    qi::rule<Iterator, V2(),             qi::space_type> v2;
    qi::rule<Iterator, V3(),             qi::space_type> v3;
};

int main() {
    using Iterator = std::string::const_iterator;

    std::string const sample = "VertexProperty {\n"
        " vertex [ 0.0 0.0 1.0,\n"
        "     1.0 1.0 1.0,\n"
        "     1.0 0.0 1.0]\n"
        " normal [1.0 0.0 0.0,\n"
        "     0.0 1.0 0.0,\n"
        "     0.0 0.0 1.0]\n"
        " texCoord [0.0 0.0,\n"
        "     1.0 0.0,\n"
        "     1.0 1.0]\n"
        "}";

    auto f = sample.begin(), l = sample.end();
    VertexProperty data;
    bool ok = qi::parse(f, l, Parser<Iterator>(), data);

    if (ok) {
        std::cout << "Parsed: " << data.vertices.size() << ", " << data.normals.size() << ", " << data.texCoords.size() << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }

    if (f!=l)
        std::cout << "Remaining input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed: 3, 3, 3
```

With debug info

```
<vertexproperty>
  <try>VertexProperty {\n ve</try>
  <v3>
    <try> 0.0 0.0 1.0,\n     1</try>
    <success>,\n     1.0 1.0 1.0,\n</success>
    <attributes>[[0, 0, 1]]</attributes>
  </v3>
  <v3>
    <try>\n     1.0 1.0 1.0,\n </try>
    <success>,\n     1.0 0.0 1.0]\n</success>
    <attributes>[[1, 1, 1]]</attributes>
  </v3>
  <v3>
    <try>\n     1.0 0.0 1.0]\n </try>
    <success>]\n normal [1.0 0.0 0</success>
    <attributes>[[1, 0, 1]]</attributes>
  </v3>
  <v3>
    <try>1.0 0.0 0.0,\n     0.</try>
    <success>,\n     0.0 1.0 0.0,\n</success>
    <attributes>[[1, 0, 0]]</attributes>
  </v3>
  <v3>
    <try>\n     0.0 1.0 0.0,\n </try>
    <success>,\n     0.0 0.0 1.0]\n</success>
    <attributes>[[0, 1, 0]]</attributes>
  </v3>
  <v3>
    <try>\n     0.0 0.0 1.0]\n </try>
    <success>]\n texCoord [0.0 0.0</success>
    <attributes>[[0, 0, 1]]</attributes>
  </v3>
  <v2>
    <try>0.0 0.0,\n     1.0 0.</try>
    <success>,\n     1.0 0.0,\n    </success>
    <attributes>[[0, 0]]</attributes>
  </v2>
  <v2>
    <try>\n     1.0 0.0,\n     </try>
    <success>,\n     1.0 1.0]\n}</success>
    <attributes>[[1, 0]]</attributes>
  </v2>
  <v2>
    <try>\n     1.0 1.0]\n}</try>
    <success>]\n}</success>
    <attributes>[[1, 1]]</attributes>
  </v2>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[[[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]], [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1]]]]</attributes>
</vertexproperty>
```

Comment: Complete rewrite of answer, because I misread the question. Now with complete [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9a8c8ba7a963682)